# ms access vba error 3021 no current record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using MS Access VBA to import from an iSeries table.  Sometimes the IBM table can be empty, which is ok.  However, when this occurs I receive VBA error 3021 - do I need to change my code or can I just suppress the error message.  Here is my code:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

'Open recordset to local table
Set rsL = New ADODB.Recordset
rsL.Open sTBL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

rs.MoveFirst
Debug.Print "AS400"
Do Until rs.EOF
  Debug.Print rs.Fields("DROP"), rs.Fields("STDATE"), rs.Fields("ENDATE")
  rsL.AddNew
  rsL.Fields("DROP") = rs.Fields("DROP")
  rsL.Fields("STDATE") = rs.Fields("STDATE")
    rsL.Fields("ENDATE") = rs.Fields("ENDATE")
  rsL.Update
  rs.MoveNext
Loop

'Test to check if above code actually worked
rsL.MoveFirst
Debug.Print "Local"
Do Until rsL.EOF
  Debug.Print rsL.Fields("DROP"), rsL.Fields("STDATE"), rsL.Fields("ENDATE")
  rsL.MoveNext
Loop

'Clear memory
Set rs = Nothing
Set rsL = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it - just changed the code to the below:

```
'rs.MoveFirst
Debug.Print "AS400"
Do Until rs.EOF
rs.MoveFirst
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `rs.MoveFirst` after opening a recordset - it's always on the first record (if there are any) or EOF (if not).

Answer (score 0):

Before you use the rsL.MoveFirst you need to check to see if the recordset is empty.
If **rsL.RecordCount <> 0** then
    rsL.MoveFirst
 End If